# Gradle Eclipse not working

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-plugin

My `build.gradle` script:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

dependencies {
    compile (
        'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.14.1',
        'org.apache.camel:camel-mail:2.14.1'
    )
}
```

When I run `gradle eclipse` I see:

```
:myapp:eclipseClasspath
:myapp:eclipseJdt
:myapp:eclipseProject
:myapp:eclipse

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.694 secs
```

When I run `gradle clean build` I get a similar `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message. But when I refresh my project in Eclipse, I don't see a `Referenced Libraries` folder with Camel Core or Camel Mail in it, instead under the `Problems` tab I see 3 problems:

- Project 'myapp' is missing required library: 'D:\workspace\myapp\unresolved dependency - org.apache.camel camel-core 2.14.1'
- Project 'myapp' is missing required library: 'D:\workspace\myapp\unresolved dependency - org.apache.camel camel-mail 2.14.1'
- The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

**What is going on here?** On a perhaps-somewhat-related note, I am on Eclipse Juno, and going into Properties >> Java >> Compiler, I don't seem to have an option to set my Eclipse Java Compiler to 1.8, only 1.7. Perhaps my Eclipse instance is too old to handle Java 8?

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you use? What version of Gradle do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your full build script, you're missing repository definitions (where to go get the artifacts).  Try adding:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Here's the [backing class](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html) for `repositories {}` in case you need to add a custom URL.